# Ajax calls - send_data and render a partial - two render methods in a single action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials

Users can download reports via a link, and next to the link is a text flag indicating whether or not they have downloaded the file already - an 'unread' alert. I hava a partial which shows a single item in an index of reports:

```
<p id="chapter_report_index_item">
 <%= link_to "#{report.chapter_report_original_filename}", chapter_report_path(report), remote: true %>
 <%unless check_read_status?(report) %>Unread
 <%end%>
<p>
```

In chapter_reports_controller.rb I have -

```
def show
  set_chapter_report
  set_read_status_true(@chapter_report)
  send_data @chapter_report.chapter_report.read, filename: @chapter_report.chapter_report_original_filename
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And in show.js, a call to re-render this single item partial -

```
$("#chapter_report_index_item").html( "<%= j (render(partial: 'index_item', locals: {report: @chapter_report})) %>" );
```

You'll note the `check_read_status` method in the view - essentially the idea is that when the partial is displayed, the unread flag is displayed if the user has not clicked on the download link.

My problem is, I'm trying to render two things in the action: the download, and the partial. What's the technique for avoiding this?

Essentially, I want a download button that changes when the file has been downloaded.

**Update**

I'm trying to solve this though a javascript to a helper (as per comments below). My problem is that `send_file` and it's ilk are not available as methods in application_helper.rb

Essentially I've got a jQuery call to a partial which just contains a call to the download method -

```
<%= report.class.name %>
<%= report.chapter_report_original_filename %>
<%= asset_download(report) %>
```

In the helper -

```
def asset_download(object)
  object.chapter_report_original_filename
  #send_file(object.chapter_report.read, filename:object.chapter_report_original_filename)
end
```

I've put the calls to `.class.name` etc to see what's getting through. When I uncomment the `send_file` call, I get the error -

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `send_file' for #<#<Class:0x0...
```

I'm guessing cos the method is available to the ActionController not ActionView.

So the question is - how do I make controller methods available in this context? Or do I find another way to do this?

**Update 2** as per the answer below, you can call the send_file method by rendering a partial which contains the call through javascript. You need to make the method available in the helper as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418340/helper-methods-actionview-and-actioncontroller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split your action in two seperate actions (the download and the ajax call) and write some frontend (javascript) code that listens for the download click and triggers a second ajax call to the update_read_status action (for example via jquery).

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. It did occur to me to try and trigger the action from the js.erb file, but I get 'unrecognised method' errors when I try and call a method in application helper. Do you know a way round this?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do when you get your 'unrecognized method' error?

Comment: I was just trying to call a method from the erb in a js file - something like <% j download_item(@object) %> - where download_item is a method in the application helper. I'm now trying it a slightly different way - I'm going update the question.