# Helper methods, ActionView and ActionController

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, helper, partials

I have a method in `application_contoller.rb` that includes a call to `send_file`. I'm calling it from a partial that's rendered by javascript, and getting the following error -

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `send_file' for #<#<Class:0x0...
```

I can kind of see what's happening - `send_file` is a controller method, so unavailable in the way I'm using it - my question is, how do I make it available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your method in controller as helper method:

```
helper_method :send_file
```